# error when assigning onClick on a child prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i there.

considering these two components:

```
const Link: React.FC<{
    clicked?: () => {};
    Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, 'svg'>>;
    children: string;
}> = ({ Icon, children, clicked }) => {
    return (
        <div className='sidebarLink' onClick={clicked}>
            <Icon />
            <p>{children}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

const Navbar: React.FC<INavbar> = ({ setPage }) => {
    return (
        <nav className='sidebarOptions'>
            <section>
                <Link Icon={GamesIcon}>Better Games</Link>
                <Link Icon={HomeIcon}>Home</Link>
                <Link Icon={StoreIcon}>Store</Link>
                <Link Icon={DashboardIcon} onClick={() => setPage('library')}>
                    Library
                </Link>
                <Link Icon={PeopleAltIcon}>Friends</Link>
                <Link Icon={EmojiEmotionsIcon}>Unreal Engine</Link>
            </section>

            <section className='section2'>
                <p>Downloads</p>
                <p>Settings</p>
                <p>user</p>
            </section>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

I am getting this error:

> Type '{ children: string; Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { clicked?: (() => {}) | undefined; Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>; children: string; } & { ...; }'.
> Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { clicked?: (() => {}) | undefined; Icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>; children: string; } & { ...; }'.ts(2322)

what would be the right type for 'clicked' ?

regards.

Answer (score 1):

`Link` component expects a prop called `clicked`, not `onClick` - rename it.

```
<Link Icon={DashboardIcon} clicked={() => setPage('library')}>
    Library
</Link>
```

Secondly, I believe it's a *void* function, which does not return anything (`setPage` looks like a hook).

```
clicked?: () => void;
```

Anyways if `setPage` does return something, change the *void* to the stuff that it returns.

Comment: oh, my bad. i completed unnoticed that. anyway. is it fine to just specify it like this? isnt it too genetic?

Comment: @nishi Do you mean _generic_? No, it's all fine to declare props this way. You can call your props as you wish.

Comment: I mean generic because you could call clicked?: Function as well. but thats not a bit descriptive and could cause issues as well.

Comment: @nishi Function is not generic, you probably can't type what does Function return.

Comment: The definition `() => void` is actually very specific.  It says "this is a function which takes no arguments and returns nothing".  Whereas `Function` just says "this is a function".  You could not assign a function which requires an argument to `() => void`.